# Which of the following code is better?

Tags: java

Which of the following code is better and why?

First Way:

```
String[] animals = "lion tiger zebra".split(" ");
for (String animal : animals) {
    System.out.println(animal);
}
```

Second Way:

```
for (String animal : "lion tiger zebra".split(" ")) {
    System.out.println(animal);
}
```

Will the code `lion tiger zebra".split(" ")` be executed all the time the loop is repeated or just the first time.

Comment: "Optimization" .. seriously. [Read these quotes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes).

Comment: Anyway, Java is eagerly evaluated (barring short-circuit operators) - in this case that implies it is the *result* of executing the `"lion tiger zebra".split(" ")` which is iterated.

Comment: first way is better, is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way  will need memory for the variable for entire execution of the method or if its in a class then till the class is given to GC.

Second way will leave the memory of the splitted strings for GC after the loop executes.

To Answer your question `Will the code lion tiger zebra".split(" ") be executed all the time the loop is repeated or just the first time.`

It will be done just once.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference. Either way, the split operation will only be performed once.

Answer (score 1):

There is little->no difference between these two pieces of code. However, the first option is a bit more readable, but they (unless the operation is ridiculously long) will take pretty much the same time to execute.